# Problema com whereIn Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.2

Preciso executar uma consulta com os parâmetros como abaixo:

```
$questoes = Questao::leftJoin('capitulos_questoes', 'capitulos_questoes.questoes_id', '=', 'questoes.id')
            ->leftJoin('modulos_questoes', 'modulos_questoes.questoes_id', '=', 'questoes.id')
            ->leftJoin('banco_disciplinas', function($join){
                $join->on('banco_disciplinas.id', '=', 'capitulos_questoes.banco_disciplinas_id')
                    ->orOn('banco_disciplinas.id', '=', 'modulos_questoes.banco_disciplinas_id');
            })
            ->leftJoin('banco_series', function($join){
                $join->on('banco_series.id', '=', 'capitulos_questoes.banco_series_id')
                    ->orOn('banco_series.id', '=', 'modulos_questoes.banco_series_id');
            })
            ->whereIn('avaliada', $status)
            ->whereIn('tipo', $tipo)
            ->whereIn(function ($query) use ($serie){
                $query->whereIn('modulos_questoes.banco_series_id',$serie)
                    ->orWhereIn('capitulos_questoes.banco_series_id', $serie);
            })
            ->whereIn(function ($query)use ($disciplina){
                $query->whereIn('modulos_questoes.banco_disciplinas_id', $disciplina)
                    ->orWhereIn('capitulos_questoes.banco_disciplinas_id', $disciplina);
            })
            ->select('questoes.id as id', 'questao', 'serie', 'ensino', 'avaliada', 'disciplina', \DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(questoes.created_at, "%d/%m/%Y") as data'))
            ->paginate($pag);
```

Estou tendo dificuldades com a função anônima no `whereIn`. Se eu tiro a parte abaixo, a consulta funciona:

```
->whereIn(function ($query) use ($serie){
                $query->whereIn('modulos_questoes.banco_series_id',$serie)
                    ->orWhereIn('capitulos_questoes.banco_series_id', $serie);
            })
            ->whereIn(function ($query)use ($disciplina){
                $query->whereIn('modulos_questoes.banco_disciplinas_id', $disciplina)
                    ->orWhereIn('capitulos_questoes.banco_disciplinas_id', $disciplina);
            })
```

A consulta está retornando este erro:
[image: Missing argument 2 for WhereIn]

> Missing argument 2 for `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::WhereIn()`

Não sei como fazer com esses `whereIn` para funcionar.

Comment: Amanda ao invés de "fotos" copie e cole o erro, fica mais facil.

Comment: Obs: retirei o voto de fechamento, porque a confusão entre where e whereIn não é bem um "erro", e sim vai do entendimento do framework, o que me parece uma duvida valida. obs2: não fui eu quem negativou.

Comment: Eu acho a duvida válida igual citação @GuilhermeNascimento... também não fui eu quem negativou.

Comment: Apesar de eu achar que a pergunta se trata de um erro de digitação, não fui eu quem negativei também. No caso, se alguém discorda do escopo da pergunta, deve usar as opções de fechamentos. Voto é outro caso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você errou esse trecho:

```
->whereIn(function ($query) use ($disciplina){
    $query->whereIn('modulos_questoes.banco_disciplinas_id', $disciplina)
        ->orWhereIn('capitulos_questoes.banco_disciplinas_id', $disciplina);
})
```

Deveria ser:

```
->where(function ($query) use ($disciplina){
    $query->whereIn('modulos_questoes.banco_disciplinas_id', $disciplina)
        ->orWhereIn('capitulos_questoes.banco_disciplinas_id', $disciplina);
})
```

Para adicionar cláusuras where enclausuradas por parênteses, você deve utilizar sempre  `where` com `Closure`.